# Validate PDF/X compliance without Acrobat Professional

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-acrobat

I'm generating PDFs using `pdflatex`. I have found that the `pdfx` LaTeX module allows to make the files PDF/X compliant, but I would like to make sure that the generated documents are indeed compliant. Acrobat Professional provides a "preflight" tool for that. Is there any free software that can do this check, too?

Comment: this is a difficult one... Adobe changes the requirements of PDF/X between versions of Acrobat Pro, you can have a file that verifies fine in one version on preflight and fails in another version

Comment: Isn't PDF/X a standard? What I need to check is things like CMYK, embedded fonts, etc.

Comment: Since you did not specify "free" this time, allow me to recommend Amyuni PDF Analyzer. It currently support verification for PDF/A (the verification set is compatible with Acrobat 9), but it is extendable/programmable with scripts. Take a look at its features here http://www.pdfanalyzer.com/features.html, it may suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks @yums. Do you actually know any free one?

Comment: @yms: Umm, no -- 'Adobe' doesn't change requirements of PDF/X. PDF/X is defined by international working groups of prepress industry experts, accepted by ISO as a formal standard (or not). However, having said that: there is no such thing as a generic 'PDF/X'. There are a few different standards concerning that area, such as: 'PDF/X-1a:2001' (ISO 15930-1);  'PDF/X-3:2002' (ISO 15930-3); 'PDF/X-1a:2003' (ISO 15930-4); 'PDF/X-2:2003' (ISO 15930-5); 'PDF/X-3:2003' (ISO 15930-6); 'PDF/X-4' (ISO 15930-7) and 'PDF/X-5' (ISO 15930-8). Yes, it's confusing...

Comment: @yms: So you cannot validate any file as generic "PDF/X", but you can possibly validate it as "PDF/X-1a:2001".

Comment: @pipitas I probably was not clear enough. What I meant is that Adobe's implementation of the validation in preflight changes on each version. I have had files where validation fails with one or more versions and not with others.

Comment: @yms: Yes, they (Adobe) still DO have bugs in their software beyond the usual 'security' thingies...  :-)

Comment: Apache PDFbox https://pdfbox.apache.org/ has a PDF/A preflight tool, but I don't know a free PDF/X one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of any free (as in beer) or Free (as in Liberty) software that can reliably validate any of the different PDF/X-* standards.

If you need to do it regularly, and if your business depends on it, you might need to use closed source payware.

If you only need to validate a few files, you may get away with using a tool like callas Software's pdfToolbox5 ( www.callassoftware.com ) and their time limited test/evaluation license (available for Windows and Mac OSX in desktop GUI shape, and as a CLI tool for Linux/Solaris as well....).

Comment: That's my conclusion indeed. So far, I went with PDFStudio, which has a 30-day evalutation. I might consider buying one of these programs if I really need to achieve a preflight on a regular basis (although I find it sad to have to buy a full PDF creation software to use just one functionality).

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer presented in [How can I test a PDF document if it is PDF/A compliant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569129/how-can-i-test-a-pdf-document-if-it-is-pdf-a-compliant) very useful.

The free service at http://www.validatepdfa.com/ allows you to submit a PDF document by mail, the service replies with a validation report.  I haven't managed to get my document validated, although I use the `pdfx` package.

I also need to mention [Generating PDF/A compliant PDFs from pdftex](http://support.river-valley.com/wiki/index.php?title=Generating_PDF/A_compliant_PDFs_from_pdftex), which provides some insight in the `pdftex` and PDF/A topic.

Answer (score 1):

We are in 2023 now, and the LaTeX team has devoted considerable effort to enable tagged PDFs. The following code, if placed before `\documentclass`, can generate PDF/A and PDF/X compliant to the latest standards (PDF 2.0, PDF/A-4, PDF/X-6).

```latex
\DocumentMetadata{
 testphase=phase-III,
 pdfversion=2.0,
 pdfstandard=X-6
}

% content of your document
```

[Scribus](https://www.scribus.net/) in an open source InDesign alternative that can check for PDF/X-3 and PDF/X-4 compliance with his Preflight verifier.
Just open a PDF file, go to Window > Preflight Verifier and select PDF/X-4.

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446594/423407